# python: subprocess returns nothing when running scripts which take longer time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, shell, subprocess

Beginner here with `subrpocess` problem:

The below line works fine when I run both the scripts with less data which takes around 10-20minutes, however with bigger data to be processed the subprocess returns nothing once both the scripts are completed (lets say in an hour).

Also: Often with lesser data, it behaves abnormally as well i.e. not returning the status_code/going through. I then have to just run the snippet again and it works. Any solid reasoning would help alot!

```
 status_code = subprocess.run(f"python3 scriptA.py {param_1} & python3 scriptB.py {param_2}",
                                     shell=True).returncode

 if status_code == 0:
     print("subprocess ended ..")  # the control does not come here incase of huge files          
     some_other_file.main(some_param1, some_param2)
```

I fail to understand why that happens (or should I use a different approach?), Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Sample of scripts (both scriptA and scriptB):

```
def main(param_2):
    some_func_with_csv_operations()  # not returning anything
    more_funcs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    param_2 = sys.argv[1]
    main(param_2)
```

Also, no scriptA or scriptB has anywhere `sys.exit()`

**EDIT**:

Screenshot:

tried printig the `status_code` before the `if` condition, nothing was printed and in the terminal, I see a cursor just blinking.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD5fQ.png)

Also (looking for any python processes):
using `ps -ax | grep python` shows no relevant information (Picture attached)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ewxd.png)

Comment: Which means that the returned status code is not 0. Which means that one of the scripts being invoked via subprocess.run() experienced an error. Which means that you should first check those scripts, why they errored.

Comment: @pepoluan No, the scripts are fine. it often happens when the scripts are run with lesser data as well. Sometime it goes through and sometimes it does not return status_code. When both the scripts are completed. I check using `ps -ax | grep python` and see no python scripts running.

Comment: As I said, status code is not 0 means an error happened. The enclosing Python script that you shared in your question simply detected that something it ran using subprocess.run() experienced an error. Go check those two scripts; does any of them has a sys.exit(something_non_zero) within.

Comment: @pepoluan The both scripts have csv operations in it, no `sys.exit()`anywhere. It is weird because sometimes it returns the status_code and sometimes it does not. Without changing anything in the scripts. (the sccripts are fully run in anycase and produce the requried csv) but if there is no status_code I cannot move on to the next part.

Comment: Anyway I can check? like in the `else` part of `if status_code ==0:`? what should I write to see? Could it be a `timeout` issue?

Comment: Try printing out status_code prior to the "if" line. Since you used `shell=True`, that is the return code of your shell. Check the documentation of your shell, what that status_code means.

Comment: @pepoluan Should I do it without using `shell=True`?

Comment: is there any reason you're running both your scripts in one subprocess? separating the two scripts into two subprocesses will help you understand where the failure is occurring

Comment: @Shannon Im doing that to save time, since both the scripts take approx similar time.

Comment: you can run two subprocesses in parallel in python. use a `Popen` constructor rather than the `run` function and then call `wait` on each process before gathering the return codes. If you do it this way you also won't need the `shell=True`.

Comment: @Shannon could post that as an answer? Perhaps with some detail (doing what I am in subprocess.run) equivilant to Popen  would be helpful

Comment: @pepoluan i tried to print the `status_code` prior to the `if` condition. Attached a screenshot. Nothing happens. in the terminal, the cursor is only blinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your processes separately to get a better idea where the failure is occurring

```
running_processes = []
running_processes.append(subprocess.Popen(["python3", "scriptA.py", f"{param_1}"]))
running_processes.append(subprocess.Popen(["python3", "scriptB.py", f"{param_2}"]))

both_succeeded = True
for p in running_processes:
    ret = p.wait()
    if ret:   # anything other than zero will evaluate to True here
        both_succeeded = False
    cmd = " ".join(p.args)
    print(f'command "{cmd}" returned code {ret}'

if both_succeeded:
    do_more_things()
```

The above uses a list to hold the running processes so you can process them in a loop and avoid repetitive code. If you will definitely only have two subprocesses you could choose not to use the loop.

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(f"python3 scriptA.py {param_1}"))
process2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(f"python3 scriptB.py {param_2}"))

ret1 = process1.wait()
ret2 = process2.wait()

if ret1 == 0 and ret2 == 0:  # or "if not ret1 and not ret2:" would also work
    do_more_things()
```

notice that [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen) requires a list of arguments and won't accept a single string, but I've used [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) in this example to allow use of a single string for the command and achieve the same result.

Comment: Where should I add the `if` condition here?

Comment: Do you want some other code to run if both subprocess return success?

Comment: yes, once both subprocess return sucess I want to call another method: `some_other_file.main(some_param1, some_param2)` like you can see in my original quesiton

Comment: Where is `shlex` defined?

Comment: you will need `import shlex`, same as you already have `import subprocess`

Comment: Cool. let me check!

Comment: @Shanon, `if ret1 == 0 and ret2 == 0:` this method wont break even if this snippet is run under a loop right? i.e. If I have to run those subprocess multiple times with each time a different `param_1` and `param_2` value